# get user specific like by id

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

im using facebook graph , when im using https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?........
   im getting all my(User) likes , i want specific like for my fan page..

how can i get specific like by id

example there are 2 likes i want to get  only the 113854025316756(Id):

```
 {
     "name": "Finzit",
     "category": "Application",
     "id": "113854025316756",
     "created_time": "2011-02-15T16:53:41+0000"
  },
  {
     "name": "\u05d0\u05d9\u05d9\u05e4\u05d5\u05df \u05db\u05d7\u05d5\u05dc \u05dc\u05d1\u05df",
     "category": "Local business",
     "id": "228466071396",
     "created_time": "2010-08-28T18:01:21+0000"
  },
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use FQL for that, like this

```
"SELECT uid, page_id, created_time FROM page_fan 
WHERE page_id='PAGE ID' 
AND uid='USER ID'";
```

Comment: +1 [FQL = Facebook Query Language](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)